# How to transfer data greater than MTU using DPDK?

Tags: dpdk, mtu

My current network stack running on DPDK supports MTU of 1500 bytes. How can I send+receive data more than 1500 bytes?

I am thinking in terms of Generic Receive Offload (GRO).

Answer (score 0):

DPDK has GRO library, have a look at [DPDK Programmer's Guide](https://doc.dpdk.org/guides/prog_guide/generic_receive_offload_lib.html)

There are calls like `rte_gro_reassemble_burst()` and an example in `testpmd`.

There is also an [IP fragmentation/reassembly library](https://doc.dpdk.org/guides/prog_guide/ip_fragment_reassembly_lib.html) with examples.